# How to design DevExpress "Detail Tabs" and filling it by Lists?

Tags: list, devexpress, datasource, master-detail

I am new in using the DevExpress tools.
I have designed a GridControl that has a main GridView and three other Gridviews in the next level. 
I turned the oprions of the main GridView : EnableMasterViewMode = True, and EnableDetailToolTip = true.

I want to design something like that presented at:
http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/MasterDetail/DetailTabs.aspx

So:

1. My design just present the first level when I run the project, How could I get the view of the nested Grids that appears at the previous link?
2. The data that I will bind in the grid are stored at run time in Lists, not in a database, so how could I fill the grid cells and columns from that Lists rather than a database?

Answer (score 1):

[Source:](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q93769.aspx)

If you are using WinForms then Please review the following help topics: [Binding Controls to Data Created at Runtime](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument2387), 
[How to: Bind a Control to Data Created at Runtime](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument2389).

The `GridControl` automatically treats properties that return the collection as master-detail relations.
So, you only should implement the corresponding properties in your classes and assign a master collection to the `GridControl.DataSource` property just in the same way you do for a standard .Net DataGridView control. This task isn't specific to our XtraGrid. 
Please also try the GridUnboundMasterView module of the GridTutorials project shipped with the XtraGrid.

The Grid creates a detail view for properties implementing the IList interface only at its root level. This behavior is described in the [GridControl - Detail views are now created if a detail collection type is an interface type inherited from IList](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q450324.aspx) ticket. A recommended approach is to implement the IList interface together with IList. In this case, the Grid will automatically create detail views as described in the [Implement Master-Detail Relationships for Objects via Collection Properties](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5496) help topic. You can also provide a master-detail relationship via events as described [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument732).

example code snippet:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = new NestedRecords();
//... 
public class NestedRecords : ArrayList {
    public NestedRecords() {
        Add(new NestedRecord("Customers", new ChildRecordsCustomers()));
        Add(new NestedRecord("Products", new ChildRecordsProducts()));
        Add(new NestedRecord("Shippers", new ChildRecordsShippers()));
    }
    public virtual new NestedRecord this[int index] {
        get { return (NestedRecord)(base[index]); }
    }
}
```

Reference:
[Master detail with IList property](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q130400.aspx)
[Using master detail with iList](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q295225.aspx)
[How to create the master-details gridcontrol with Ilist](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q453850.aspx)
[How does XtraGrid detects a Collection for Master-Detail grids](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q385648.aspx)

If you are using WebForms then Please review the following documentation help topic: [Master-Detail Relationship](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3772) and try to implement taking collection dataSource rather than dataTable.